# Is there a way to disable dynamic forms for an object?

Tags: dynamic-forms

I upgraded a lightning record page for a custom object to be a dynamic form in hopes of configuring field visibility settings. Unfortunately my org is managed and the dynamic forms functionality does not seem to be compatible, and it broke my page layout beyond repair. Is there any way to undo the upgrade from a dynamic form back to the way it was? Rebuilding a new page layout may not be possible either. Thank you!

Comment: Are you just using only Dynamic Actions or are you using the fields as well to display dynamically based on other fields?

Comment: Good question! My intention was to use the fields to display dynamically based on other fields, however other custom settings in our org prevent this and I am now just hoping to change it back if possible since it being a dynamic form is having unintended third order effects.

Answer (score 0):

No need to revert it just add detail tab or standard once and remove the dynamic once.